# CSVPrinter new line character

Tags: java, csv

I used com.Ostermiller.util.CSVPrinter to print report csv file.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream csvOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
CSVPrinter csvp = new CSVPrinter(csvOut);

for(SiteSector siteSector : siteSectorList){
    siteSectors.append(siteSector.getSector().getName()).append("   Description: ").append(siteSector.getSector().getDescription())
    .append("   Primary: ").append(siteSector.isDefaultSector() ? "Yes" : "No").append("\r\n");}

String[] contents = new String[]{siteCodes.toString(), siteSectors.toString()};

csvp.writeln(contents);
```

The "\r\n" does not work as expected as creating new line as below,
[image: new line]

Could someone please advise me how to add new line character?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

`writeln()` stands for "write line".

You have to invoke `csvp.writeln()` for every line that you want to write (from within your for loop) - no need for adding manual line separators.

Comment: Thanks your response. The characters ('\r\n') is still showing up instead of making new line after used System.lineSeparator().

Comment: Yes, it was the wrong approach - see my updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not solve the issue as still showing "\r\n"

Comment: You have to invoke csvp.writeln() for every line that you want to write (from within your for loop) - **no need for adding manual line separators** (\r\n)